# Does Hibernate/Spring write immediately to database if no @Transactional is used?

Tags: mysql, spring, multithreading, hibernate, thread-safety

I summarize the case below, but what I am facing seems to be a "lost update" issue even though I am using locks that do not allow more than one thread at a time to be able to write to the DB.

Locks, i.e., reentrant locks, synchronized, semaphores, etc, all work well in preventing more than one thread to gain access to the shared area.. no issue here. The following is the setup in a nutshell:

I get two Java threads as a result of two users clicking on a button to increase a counter.  Each user issues repeated updates to the counter, which is a field in a Mysql table. Basically, If users click on the button slowly, there is no lost update.  When they speed up the clicking on the UI of each user,  I see the missed updates.

In order to prevent the two threads from stepping on each other's foot, each thread needs to get a lock to the shared code area.  I would not use java locks if I had multiple servers.  The whole application is on a single server.

What I am seeing is that even though a thread writes to the database and releases the lock, the next thread sees some older value for the field.  I removed all @Transactional statements to rule out any Spring tranactions issues, but the lost update is still there.

So, if the repository (DAO) writes to Mysql, doesn't that guarantee that the value is committed and persisted? Remember, no @Transactional statements are used here. I also tried flush after save in the repository module.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: Show us the generated SQL so we can determine if the chosen locking mechanism actually mapped correctly to a MySQL transaction.  Also, do you (or Hibernate) have tests for errors after each SQL operation?  If not, you may have a "deadlock" that went unnoticed.  Also check `SHOW ENGINE=InnoDB STATUS;`

Comment: In the debugging I did no two threads go into protected code at same time.  Still, I do not see why after a thread is done saving to DB and releases lock, next thread is not seeing the update.  That seems to violate what is expected from the save method.

Comment: More details, please, on the "lock".

Comment: The failure to "update" was probably accompanied by an error that was ignored.

Comment: Rick I am thinking the only way this can happen is if there was a rollback when one of the threads was doing the update. I am using a static reentrant lock in class LockClass:  
 ``public static ReentrantLock lockResource = new ReentrantLock();``  

Each thread does lock and unlock:  
              ``LockClass.lockResource.lock();
                try {``
*********** update database ************
                ``    } finally {
                        LockClass.lockResource.unlock();
                    }``  
If there was a roll back, how do I know it took place and why it happened?

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` annotation is always used for data modifying methods. It is used not only for a transaction itself, but to open and close a persistent context (Hibernate session) too!

For example you can check an implementation of `JpaRepository` `save()` method

```java
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

        if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
            em.persist(entity);
            return entity;
        } else {
            return em.merge(entity);
        }
    }
```

An idea to use java locks is not very good. Why you have such behavior? I think it is not a transactional issue, probably you have implemented multithreading code incorrectly.

The best way is to use JPQL `update` to update a counter

```
update ButtonEntity set couner = counter + 1 where id = :buttonId
```

Another option is to use a pessimistic lock.

Comment: Yes that does show that @Transactional is used under the hood.